# A downloaded website template appears full of executables on Mac OS X, should I be worried?

Tags: html, css, macos, file, operating-system

I've been playing around with Bootstrap and building responsive websites, and I downloaded a website template that, on my Mac, appears to be full of executables (see screenshot below).

The README appears to be executable, along with all CSS, WOFF, EOT, LESS and SCSS files. However, carefully opening them in a very obscure text editor reveals that they contain exactly what you'd expect. The CSS files contain CSS code. The README contains some info on the template. I haven't checked them all, but they seem to just be mis-recognized as executable files. **Should I be worried?**

I'm considering `chmod`ing the files just in case and removing executable permission, but that may  just be me misunderstanding the Unix permission system. What's going on, and what should I do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me from time to time. In your case, what is most likely going on is that the resource fork for the file wasn't transferred along with the file (or didn't exist in the first place). You can read more about this occurrence here:

https://macosx.com/threads/what-is-a-unix-executable-file-why-is-it-doing-this.302267/

I don't think that CHMOD will help you fix this problem. In the past, what has helped me is renaming the extension manually. Does this solve the problem for you?

Comment: I tried to change the extension on the css files. I changed it to txt, the exec icon changed to txt, I changed it back and the exec icon came back.

Comment: An alternative way to do it is to do Apple-I to get info on the file. That has worked to associate files properly for me in the past. What happens when you do this?

Comment: Apple-I (Command-I) just shows info on the file, equivalent to right-clicking the file and selecting "Get Info." If I compare, for example, a css file that appears as an executable to a css file from a previous project that does not, the info pane shows identical data, with the obvious exception of the file path. Nothing new